# Twilio Gather - when a user hits pound without entering digits it does not proceed to next verb

Tags: php, twilio

Having some trouble with twilio gather verb, hoping for some help

I want to collect a 6 digit account number from users, but if they don't know their account number, they should be able to hit pound to continue without waiting.

The behaviour I experience is:
- user enters 6 digits, no problem, billing php is called.
- user enters fewer than 6 digits, billing php is called after timeout
- user enters nothing, gather times out and we redirect to call handler xml

finally:
- user enters only pound, we have a problem, it just starts the "say" verb over again. every time they hit pound, we get the Say verb again.

SO there's no way to skip the input except by the user timing out...?

code:

```
<Gather action="v2level2-billing.php" numDigits="6" finishOnKey="#">
    <Say voice="alice" loop="5">
        Please enter your six digit user number. If you do not know your user number, press pound.
    </Say>
</Gather>
<Redirect>v2call-handler.xml</Redirect>
```

thanks!

Comment: What does `v2call-handler.xml` say?

Comment: It's our root answer script. Note I discovered that pressing # just escapes the current Say loop iteration, and will proceed to the Redirect only after the user hears the Say all 5 times. So removing the loop solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather

> If the 'timeout' is reached before the caller enters any digits, or if the caller enters the 'finishOnKey' value before entering any other digits, Twilio will not make a request to the 'action' URL but instead continue processing the current TwiML document with the verb immediately following the `<Gather>`.

Thus, it should be proceeding to `<Redirect>v2call-handler.xml</Redirect>`. If it isn't, contact Twilio support.

Comment: Yes I read that over and over and thought the same thing. I just thought I must be missing something...

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out - if you hit # without entering numbers, it proceeds to the next iteration of the  loop. In this case, the xml redirect is only called if you hit # key five times.

I still don't think this is correct behaviour, as the documentation clearly implies that pressing # will jump out of the  - but removing the loop solves the issue for now.